# std::string class inheritance and tedious c++ overload resolution #2

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-studio-2015, gcc5

Previous question: [std::string class inheritance and tedious c++ overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155089/stdstring-class-inheritance-and-tedious-c-overload-resolution)

In steps after the previous question i have tried to test `operator+` over the raw string pointer: `"aaa" + path_string{ "bbb" }`. And found it does not call the respective `path_string` class friend function.

I tried to add not template overload `operator+` `(2)` but it didn't work either. But i've found that the templated one `(3)` did work.

```
#include <string>

template <class t_elem, class t_traits, class t_alloc>
class path_basic_string : public std::basic_string<t_elem, t_traits, t_alloc>
{
public:
    using base_type = std::basic_string<t_elem, t_traits, t_alloc>;

    path_basic_string() = default;
    path_basic_string(const path_basic_string & ) = default;
    path_basic_string(path_basic_string &&) = default;

    path_basic_string & operator =(path_basic_string path_str)
    {
        this->base_type::operator=(std::move(path_str));
        return *this;
    }

    path_basic_string(base_type r) :
        base_type(std::move(r))
    {
    }

    path_basic_string(const t_elem * p) :
        base_type(p)
    {
    }

    base_type & str()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    const base_type & str() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;

    // ... all over operators are removed as not related to the issue ...

    // (1)
    friend path_basic_string operator+ (const t_elem * p, const base_type & r)
    {
        path_basic_string l_path = p;
        l_path += "xxx";
        return std::move(l_path);
    }

    friend path_basic_string operator+ (const t_elem * p, base_type && r)
    {
        if (!r.empty()) {
            return "111" + ("/" + r); // call base operator instead in case if it is specialized for this
        }

        return "111";
    }

    // (2)
    friend path_basic_string operator+ (const t_elem * p, path_basic_string && r)
    {
        base_type && r_path = std::move(std::forward<base_type>(r));
        if (!r_path.empty()) {
            return "222" + ("/" + r_path); // call base operator instead in case if it is specialized for this
        }

        return "222";
    }

    // (3) required here to intercept the second argument
    template <typename T>
    friend path_basic_string operator+ (const t_elem * p, T && r)
    {
        base_type && r_path = std::move(std::forward<base_type>(r));
        if (!r_path.empty()) {
            return "333" + ("/" + r_path); // call base operator instead in case if it is specialized for this
        }

        return "333";
    }
};

using path_string = path_basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >;

std::string test_path_string_operator_plus_right_xref(path_string && right_path_str)
{
    return "aaa" + right_path_str;
}

int main()
{
    const path_string test =
        test_path_string_operator_plus_right_xref(std::move(path_string{ "bbb" }));
    printf("-%s-\n", test.str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

The output for 3 compilers: gcc 5.4, clang 3.8.0, msvc 2015 (19.00.23506)

> -333/bbb-

https://rextester.com/BOFUS59590

As i remembered the C++ standard clarifies this like as a templated function has to be lookup only when no one not templated function is matched arguments exactly. But the `(2)` operator has to be matched exactly, but why then it is not even called?

If remove `(3)` then the `(1)` would call instead of `(2)` which is matches better than `(1)`.

What is going on here?

**PS**: I think this is the same issue around the `const` + `single reference` like from previous question.

Comment: Note that `std::move(std::forward<T>(...))` is redundant, `std::move(...)` should give the same result. You always get an rvalue reference either way. And in the context of your operators, neither `std::move` nor `std::forward` do anything. It's not clear to me where the confusion lies exactly, but you misunderstand how move semantics work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `std::forward` casts a reference to a reference to a different type (base class in this case), then `std::move` changes a forwarded reference to a rvalue reference, eh? Could be simply `static_cast<base_type &&>(r)` probably though.

Comment: @bipll I'm not sure what you are asking. But `base_type` is never a reference type, so `std::forward` doesn't perform any perfect forwarding (`T` is ignored completely). Adding `std::move` guaranties you would ignore perfect forwarding by always moving (and failing to compile if you can't). Edit : to respond to the edit to your comment, that cast is essentially just `std::move`.

Comment: my question is `why (3) calls instead of (2)`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I wrote so just to explicitly state i want a move over the base type instead of derived.

Comment: What's a reference to a reference?

Comment: Aside from the issue at hand - how sure are you that your code will never experience slicing issues? This all looks extremely prone to accidental misuse (both inside and outside your influence).

Comment: @MaxLanghof slicing is not a problem here, i won't store anything in the derived class anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not asking anything. The variable cast is of reference type `T &&`, which is either `U &&` or `U &`, where `U` is `std::decay_t<T>` and is a subclass of `base_type`. By such chain of calls it is finally cast to `base_type &&`.

Answer (score 2):

In following snippet:

```
std::string test_path_string_operator_plus_right_xref(path_string && right_path_str)
{
    return "aaa" + right_path_str;
}
```

`right_path_str` is a non-const l-value. Because of that, it can never bind to an rvalue reference.

When template overload is not available, it binds to const lvalue reference overload in

```
friend path_basic_string operator+ (const t_elem * p, const base_type & r)
```

and when template is there, it's a better match for non-const lvalue reference:

```
template <typename T>
friend path_basic_string operator+ (const t_elem * p, T && r)
```

In this case, `T&&` is a forwarding reference, which collapses to non-const lvalue reference. To fix your code, make sure to `move` from rvalue reference arguments when calling functions and make it a habit - whenever you pass an rvalue reference below, use `std::move`, and whenever you pass forwarding reference, use `std::forward`.

```
std::string test_path_string_operator_plus_right_xref(path_string && right_path_str)
{
    return "aaa" + std::move(right_path_str);
}
```

Comment: If i understant you correctly the templated `T &&` can binds to both either `const blabla &` or `blabla &&`, when `blabla &&` only to `blabla &&`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Andry The templated `T&&` can bind to anything (keyword: forwarding references). It is different from a `path_string&&`, which only binds to temporaries.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Why then it does not bind to itself? The function argument type is `path_string &&`.

Comment: The function argument _is not_ of type `path_string&&`, it _binds to_ something of type `path_string&&`. The argument itself is an lvalue, because it has a name. Yes, this distinction is quite confusing at first.

Comment: @Andry an l-value can never bind to rvalue reference. Period. And in `Foo&& f` f is an l-value unless Foo is a template argument to a function. Reiterating: rvalue references are lvalues!

Comment: @SergeyA In other words it must be templated to bind to r-value, right? It makes sence.